# Best method to scan a CSV file for a value in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am looking for advice on how to best handle a programming task using Delphi 7.

I have the need to be able to quickly identify a value from a CSV file (less than 15kb in size). The CSV file exists in format of:

Chapter number, Paragraph number, Total number of words in the paragraph

I want to be able to retrieve this last value, i.e., the number of words, by providing a function the first two values (i.e., the chapter and paragraph number).

The CSV file is sorted numerically, that is:

```
1,1,30    // first paragraph of first chapter  (line # 1)
1,2,56    // second paragraph of first chapter  (line # 2)
1,3,101
1,4,56
...
2,1,78
2,2,51
...
100,1,87
100,2,101
...
100,23,78    // last paragraph of last chapter (line # 1500)
```

So in the example above, I'd like to pass 2,2 to a function and have it return "51" (integer)

I'd like to avoid using a database table because: 1) the amount of data isn't that large (1500 lines in the CSV file, i.e., 1500 paragraphs), 2) the extra overhead of a database engine (I only need to read data, not write data), 3) the frequency that this function will be called from within the program.

What would you recommend, and why?

Comment: You could use an initial loaded AdoDataset or Clientdataset with CreateDataset as MemoryTable and use `Locate` to get you values. You also could build a binary tree or cheaper an Array of Records or a List of own classes and search them binary. Depending on your focus you can choose the easiest to implement or fastet solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TYPE
  TTwoDimIntArr = ARRAY OF ARRAY OF Cardinal;

PROCEDURE SetValue(VAR ARR : TTwoDimIntArr ; Chapter,Paragraph,Value : Cardinal);
  BEGIN
    IF Chapter>=LENGTH(ARR) THEN SetLength(ARR,SUCC(Chapter));
    IF Paragraph>=LENGTH(ARR[Chapter]) THEN SetLength(ARR[Chapter],SUCC(Paragraph));
    ARR[Chapter,Paragraph]:=Value
  END;

FUNCTION GetValue(CONST ARR : TTwoDimIntArr ; Chapter,Paragraph : Cardinal) : Cardinal;
  BEGIN
    IF Chapter>=LENGTH(ARR) THEN
      Result:=0
    ELSE IF Paragraph>=LENGTH(ARR[Chapter]) THEN
      Result:=0
    ELSE
      Result:=ARR[Chapter,Paragraph]
  END;

FUNCTION ParseFile(CONST FileName : STRING) : TTwoDimIntArr;
  VAR
    SL  : TStrings;
    S   : STRING;
    P,Q : Cardinal;
    {$IFDEF DELPHI7 }
      I : Cardinal;
    {$ENDIF }

  BEGIN
    SL:=TStringList.Create;
    TRY
      SL.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      {$IFDEF DELPHI7 }
      FOR I:=1 TO SL.Count DO BEGIN
        S:=SL[PRED(I)];
      {$ELSE }
      FOR S IN SL DO BEGIN
      {$ENDIF }
        P:=POS(',',S);
        Q:=PosEx(',',S,SUCC(P));
        SetValue(Result,StrToInt(COPY(S,1,PRED(P))),StrToInt(COPY(S,SUCC(P),PRED(Q-P))),StrToInt(COPY(S,SUCC(Q),255)))
      END
    FINALLY
      SL.Free
    END
  END;
```

ParseFile parses the file and returns it in a two-dimensional dynamic array. If you are 100% sure that you don't exceed the boundaries of the array you can access it directly. Otherwise the GetValue function is a safe wrapper to access the contents of the array.

Use it as:

```
USES ... StrUtils ...;

.
.<My Code>
.
VAR ARR : TTwoDimIntArr;

BEGIN
  ARR:=ParseFile(<FileName>);
  .
  .
  .
  Words:=GetValue(ARR, <Chapter>, <Paragraph>);
  .
  .
END.
```

If Delphi 7 doesn't have the PosEx function in StrUtils, you can code it as follows:

```
FUNCTION PosEx(CONST SearchFor,SearchIn : STRING ; StartPos : Cardinal = 1) : Cardinal;
  BEGIN
    Result:=POS(SearchFor,COPY(SearchIn,StartPos,$7FFFFFFF));
    IF Result>0 THEN INC(Result,PRED(StartPos))
  END;
```

Comment: Delphi 7 *does* have the PosEx function, however, Delphi 7 does not know how to handle the FOR S IN SL DO BEGIN in the ParseFile function.

Comment: I have updated the code to show how to do it in Delphi 7 for anyone who isn't familiar with the FOR...IN syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing your own code, why not use the, possibly little known, CommaText property of TStrings?

An example of using CommaText is shown below.
CODE

```
var
  s: TStringList;
begin
  s := TStringList.Create;
  try
    s.CommaText := 'a, b, "c,d"';
    ShowMessage( s[0] );
    ShowMessage( s[1] );
    ShowMessage( s[2] );
  finally
    s.Free;
  end;
end;
```

> Will Display Quote: a b c,d

as the output of the three ShowMessage calls.

Andrew

Hampshire, UK

Answer (score 1):

If file is not that big (~few kilobytes), I'd recommend to read it to memory, and search for #13#10',,'. The next number after this string will be number you are searching for (of course, if there are no extra spaces in your file).

Comment: So you are saying use LoadFromFile() to load the entire file into a single string, then perform a Pos(#13#10+'2,2,TheString)?

Comment: Yeah, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would create two-dimensional array

```
Book[Chapter, Paragraph]
```

and fill it manually by reading the file.

And the function will be trivial:

```
GetNumberOfPages(Chapter: integer; Paragraph: integer): integer;
begin
  Result := Book[Chapter, Paragraph];
end;
```

If you are looking for 3-rd party tools, JEDi could an option

http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvCsvDataSet

Answer (score 1):

With a 2dim array you need a stringlist helper as temp:

```
BEGIN
    SL:=TStringList.Create;
    sltemp:= TStringList.Create;
   TRY
      SL.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      writeln('Scikit Boston Samples: '+itoa(sl.count-1))
       FOR I:= 0 TO SL.Count-1 DO BEGIN
        S:=SL[(I)];
        SLtemp.CommaText:= S;
        for sll:= start-1 to col-1 do   
          SetValue(Result,I,Sll,StrToFloat(sltemp[sll]))
       END;
   FINALLY
      sltemp.free;
      SL.Free
   END
```